# Extremely Basic Python Program Doesn't Return Proper Value

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a very simple program that calculates how far an object has fallen due to gravity given how long it's been in the air.

```
(main.py)

# Importing falling_distance function 
from a3_functions import falling_distance 

# Doc-string
import a3_functions; print(a3_functions.falling_distance.__doc__)

# Input from user and formatted output
t = input('Enter the time (in secs): ')
print("The Object has fallen {:.2f} in {:d} seconds".format(falling_distance(t), t))
```

^^ Being the main module/class where the user puts in the amount of time. After that it references the program a3_functions.py which is essentially a library for various functions.

```
 (a3_functions.py)

 def falling_distance (t): 
"""-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Purpose: Calculate and output falling distance (in metres) given time (in 
 seconds) 
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Preconditions: 
      t - time (int > 0)
      g - gravitational constant
 Postconditions:
      returns:
      d - distance (float > 0)
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
""" 

t = int(t)
g = 9.8 
d = (1/2)*g*t**2 
return d
```

I know i can do it very simply in one program but can anyone tell me when d is being returned as 0?

In my opinion, i think it has something to do with the way eclipse is set up because it worked before. I worked on other programs, came back to this one and it broke. I feel like this is a simple problem that happens way too often and has an easy fix

Comment: Are you sure you’re using Python 3? What happens when you type `import sys` and then `sys.version` in the Python shell?

Comment: using python 3.6

Comment: apparently changing the (1/2) to 0.5 fixed the problem....

Comment: Then you are using Python 2. The way division of integers works changed in python 3. That’s why I asked you to explicitly check the version.

Comment: Also, your format code does not work in python 3, because the `input` function changed.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Python 2, not Python 3. They are often both installed on the same computer, and on most systems the default is 2 instead of 3. If you explicitly start it with `python3` instead of just `python`, you should be able to get Python 3 if it’s installed.

Specifically, in Python 2, if you divide two integers, it converts the result to an integer, so `1/2` gives 0. This was changed to do floating-point division in Python 3.

Additionally, the `input` function in Python 2 is equivalent to `eval(input(...))` in Python 3, so `t` is already an `int`. In Python 3, your format call doesn’t work because you can’t use `{:d}` on a string.

Comment: how do I get rid of Py 2, because i ran sys.version on the console and it explicitly showed 3.6, however i do use eclipse for projects

Comment: nevermind, I just deleted the python 2 interpreter and kept the 3.6 one